# Can Zabbix be used with PostgreSQL PAAS?

Tags: postgresql, zabbix

I'm planning to migrate our Zabbix server on-prem to Azure using the latest Zabbix version. We are using PostgreSQL as our database. Does  Zabbix support PostgreSQL paas?

If not, what would be the best way to migrate the database from on-prem (running in Cent7 with Zabbix server 5.0.X) to Azure with minimal downtime?

Comment: you may be looking for the ODBC template: https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/postgresql#postgresql_odbc